# Is it true that $2^p\|f\|^p_{L_p} >2\|f\|^p_{L_\infty}$?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

For any $C^1$ function defined in $(0,1)$, is it true that
$$ 2^p\|f\|^p_{L_p} >2\|f\|^p_{L_\infty}
$$
If it is true, how to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. Consider, for $\delta>0$,
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{(x-\delta)^2}{\delta^2},&\mbox{ if } x\in[0,\delta]\\ 0,&\mbox{ otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Then $\|f\|_\infty=\|f\|_\infty^p=1$, and 
$$
\|f\|_p^p=\frac1{\delta^2}\int_0^\delta(x-\delta)^{2p}\,dx=\frac1{\delta^2}\left.\frac{(x-\delta)^{2p+1}}{2p+1}\right|_0^\delta=\frac{\delta^{2p-1}}{2p+1}.
$$
As $\delta$ can be chosen arbitrarily small, the inequality can be made to fail.

Comment: Thanks! How about if I add $2^p\|f'\|^p_{L_p}$ to the left hand side?

Comment: Better yet: let $f$ be a characteristic function on the unit interval. $||f||_p = 1 = ||f||_{\infty}$.

Comment: @Yourent: you can always get $f'=0$ with arbitrarily large infinity norm.

Comment: @Cameron: the only characteristic function that is $C^1$ on $(0,1)$ is the constant function $1$; that one does satisfy the inequality.